# Why hibernate.cfg.xml is not being deployed?

Tags: hibernate, maven, javafx

I've built an javafx application using maven. The app uses hibernate to connect to a database. But when I deploy it using the javafx-maven-plugin (mvn clean jfx:jar) it doesn't deploy the hibernate.cfg.xml.

My pom.xml:

```
<build>

        <finalName>App_Name</finalName>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.company.app_name.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Where you have placed `hibernate.cfg.xml` in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all the resources to the `src/main/resources`.

By default, anything except `.java` files are ignored from the `src/main/java`, by the javafx-maven-plugin.